# How to use bulk insert condition for particular number of records inside for loop

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, asp.net-core

I want to use the bulk insert concept in C# once count reach 20.if we have 40 numbers no issue. but if we get 39 records got a problem, based on if the condition. how we able to avoid this problem. here below I added a simple program for reference.

```
var numbers = 39  // not static numbers
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<=numbers; i++)
{

 count++;
 if (count == 20)
   {
      //Logic
      count = 0;
   }

}
```

Comment: is your for loop starts from zero?

Comment: Yes loop start from Zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine whether to batch insert the rest files by comparing the counter with the remaining number of files.

```
int num = 49;
int count = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
    count++;
    var n = i / 20;
    if(i % 20 == 0 ||count == (num - 20 * ( i / 20)))
    {
        //Logic        
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of count variable, you can use [modulo operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) inside for loop

Like

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numbers; i++)
{
    //i != 0 to avoid bulk process at first
    if(i != 0 && i % 20 == 0)
    {
       //Your bulk operation
    }

}
```

---

I recommend you to use `Console.WriteLine()` to print value of `i` and `counter` in each iteration so that you will understand bug in your code.

```
var numbers = 39  // not static numbers
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<=numbers; i++)
{

 count++;

 //Print values to understand flow of program 
 Console.WriteLine($"For i = {i}, value of count is {count}");

 if (count == 20)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Time to reset count variable");
      //Logic
      count = 0;

   }

}
```

---

You can use Linq `.Skip()` and `.Take()`, to do batches

```
var batchSize = 20;
var batchCount = files.Count() / batchSize;
for (int i = 0; i < batchCount; i++)
{
  var bulkFiles = files.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer please check. Also delete unnecessary comments. This will avoid others to confuse